# Using WHERE in Laravel Returns Empty Array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do a WHERE in Laravel. My model has `id_usuario,` and in my database, I have five rows with `id_usuario = 3`, but Laravel is only returning an empty array.

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function show(Request $request)
{
    $animaisPerdidos = AnimalPerdido::where('id_usuario', $request->id);

    return response()->json($animaisPerdidos);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('selectanimalperdido', 'AnimalPerdidoController@show');
```

**In Postman**

[image]

**Model**

```
class AnimalPerdido extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $table = 'animais_perdidos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'id_usuario', 'lat', 'lng', 'id_tipo_pet', 'raca', 'id_sexo', 'data', 'possui_identificador', 'id_cores', 'informacoes_adicionais', 'nome_identificador', 'foto'
    ];  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append "**->get()**" at the end of query, like below:

```
AnimalPerdido::where('id_usuario', $request->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

use the code below for your controller "**get()** if you want an array or **first()** if you want first result":

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $animaisPerdidos = AnimalPerdido::where('id_usuario', $request->id)->get();

    return response()->json($animaisPerdidos);
}
```

Comment: This is correct - `->where(...)` returns just a query builder, to actually get the results from query builder you need to call `->where(...)->get()`, which will actually retrieve the results using the built query. Also, I don't think that `$request->id` is going to get you the input variable, as Eric pointed out and you should replace thast with `$request->get('id')` or `$request->input('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
Route::get('selectanimalperdido', 'AnimalPerdidoController@show
```

to

```
Route::get('selectanimalperdido/{id}', 'AnimalPerdidoController@show');
```

Comment: If he does that, he needs to change the controller as well, to receive the ID variable, as well as change the request url. But that's not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You need $request->input('id');

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#accessing-the-request